# Pyinstaller can not find scipy.special._ufuncs on another computer

Tags: python, windows, scipy, pyinstaller

I am trying to get setup with a easily distributable python program which happens to use scipy. I have two windows 10 64 bit virtual machines. On one I have installed the dependencies for my program, and it runs correctly. Additionally I have installed pyinstaller and performed a freeze. The program runs correctly as the building user on the first VM, as well as a new user on the first VM. The issue is that I get a error loading dll on the second VM, which I just spun up as a test.

[image: load fail]

I attempted to find all imports from scipy and include them as hidden imports. I also included the scipy "extra dll".

```
pyinstaller --windowed --icon="%SCRIPT_FOLDER%\res\icon.ico" --hidden-import=numpy --hidden-import=scipy._lib._util --hidden-import=scipy.special._ufuncs --hidden-import=scipy --hidden-import=scipy.stats --hidden-import=scipy.interpolate --hidden-import=scipy.special --hidden-import=scipy.cluster.hierarchy --paths C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll --workpath "%WORK_FOLDER%" --distpath "%OUTPUT_FOLDER%" "%SCRIPT_FOLDER%\..\something.py" -n something
```

Also, I can see the referenced dll files in the correct spot in the frozen output folder under scipy/special there are _ufuncs.cp37-win_amd64.pyd and also _ufuncs_cxx.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

The error is generated specifically on the line "from scipy import special".

Also of note, though I guess it does not help much, is that I have followed a similar procedure for OSX and Linux platforms with no such issue, and no need for any manual hidden import specification...

Would appreciate any help that you can give to help figure out what is going wrong.